# Read from a socket for n seconds

Tags: java, c++, sockets, timeout

I'd like to put a timeout reading a socket, i found this in C++ and i'd like to convert it on Java.

```
int readable_timeo(SOCKET fd, int sec){
fd_set rset;
struct timeval tv;


FD_ZERO(&rset);
FD_SET(fd, &rset);

tv.tv_sec = sec;
tv.tv_usec = 500000;

return (select(0, &rset, NULL, NULL, &tv));}
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: A read time out is used on a blocking read operation.  I believe a Selector in Java will tell you about socket(s) which have data, not tell you about sockets which failed to give you data in a given amount of time.  That is what the blocking read is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple equivalent in Java is Socket.setSoTimeout(). The equivalent of the code you posted, which isn't the simplest, is Selector.select().

Comment: Can you give me an example of this scenario?: I have a socket that is already connected and i want to pass it inside a method readSocketTimeout(Socket s, int millisec) that try to read for the millisec time.